# Too late to start plants inside? (Late April, Eastern Massachusetts, USA)

Tags: germination, container-gardening

I'm no gardening hero but I like to grow flowers, herbs and a few vegetables from seed. Usually I start them indoors but this year I had trouble getting seeds because of the pandemic.

The seeds finally came yesterday and I am wondering if there remains any advantage now to starting them inside, or if I should just wait another week or two until the weather warms up a bit more. It's been a cold Spring so far but that should change pretty soon.

I just do container gardening on my backporch, which may mean that the soil will warm faster (?)

*(If this question is too specific/localized, let me know and I will delete it)*

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the seeds you want to plant and if you're okay holding plants inside for three to four weeks.

If you're going to grow cucumbers or melons, then yes, start them inside in a very warm place or on a heating mat set to 75-80 degrees F. I would probably also start tomatoes with the intention of moving them outside in three-four weeks - they'll be small, but should grow up fast. I think basil could also work. Again - don't move these outside until at least they have their first set of true leaves.

If you want to grow things like moss rose, angelonia, and begonias, then it's too late for both inside or outside (although MAYBE you get some decent-looking moss roses by end of June if you plant them outside now).

If you want to grow marigolds, zinnias, or other fast-germinating/growing annuals, then I'd plant them in the containers outside now (with appropriate frost protection for any below freezing nights you might still get). They may not germinate until two weeks, but you won't need to transplant them this way.